# gRPC on React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, grpc

I've been working with iOS for a while now, and I'm experiementing with React Native. An obstacle I've come accross is how I can incorporate my gRPC endpoints into React Native, or if that fundamentally is possible. I've tried simply adding the generated node.js code from gRPC in to no avail.

The last answer I got was from last year [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/grpc-io/KZYkNKe8auk/jazZMJoGEQAJ).

Comment: You're likely going to have to bring in gRPC through an include and feed it the proto file as JS/node gRPC generates on the fly. However, there are several node specific libs that gRPC relies on (path for example) that don't translate over in RN land. Let me know if you get this to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Node.js gRPC library uses a native extension written in C++ to do most of the work. The [Linking Libraries](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html) page in the React Native documentation seems to indicate that such a library can be used on iOS, as long as you link it into your app directly with the [rnpm](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm) tool.

Alternatively, you may be able to use the [Objective C gRPC library](https://cocoapods.org/pods/gRPC) by following the [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content) guide in the React Native documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether I should duplicate my own answer, so, please take a look at a potential pure-JavaScript solution at:

[Implement gRPC in an iOS React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962290/implement-grpc-in-an-ios-react-native-app/50145994#50145994)

Maybe the above could ease having to link native code and still be cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on gRPC generator tool which will automatically generate Swift/Java proxies https://github.com/anjmao/rn-grpc-bridge

Currently it is already generating Swift Unary calls services. Example https://github.com/anjmao/rn-grpc-bridge/blob/master/examples/dist/book_grpc_pb_service.swift

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, [Improbable Engineering's gRP-Web](https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web) can't be used with React Native.

Instead you must use [React Native Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro) and build native modules in Java, Kotlin, Objective-C, and/or Swift.

You will:

1. implement a gRPC client in the native language of your device,
2. export it using React Native's Native module framework
3. access the native module and its gRPC methods through React Native
4. Call those exported methods in React your Native code

If, for example you are building on iOS/Swift, you'll need to do:

```
Reat Native <-> ObjC Bridge <-> Swift <-> gRPC
```

On Android it will be like this:

```
React Native <-> Android Java
```

I've written a tutorial for [Building a gPRC Client in React Native on iOS](https://gaitatzis.medium.com/building-a-grpc-client-in-react-native-on-ios-4f6dd2df31fc). I hope it is helpful.

And one for [Writing a native module for React Native using Kotlin](https://callstack.com/blog/writing-a-native-module-for-react-native-using-kotlin/)

[iOS/Objective-C](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) and [Android/Java](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) are covered by the React Native documentation